# Possible to get data added date in phpmyadmin using php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I created database but not added date column, data added last 1year but not show data added current date, possible to get data added current date, please help me

my database name `studen`

```
name
age
city
```

but not added date column, possible to get student joining date

Comment: No, MySQL doesn't automatically remember the date of additions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. If you need to know when a row was added, you should have a column like

```
date_added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and if you want to know when the row was modified, you can use a column like

```
last_modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

If you don't have anything like this in the table, MySQL doesn't save the dates automatically.

Comment: Perhaps to keep the database as lean as possible.  But is there at least a separate log of these `MySQL` transactions somewhere on the server?  Anytime a database is modified?

Comment: I think it may be possible to enable transaction logging.